# Is it possible to embed a Gtk gui in a web page?

Tags: gtk

I created a gui using Gtk in python and I would like to embed it in a web page. I searched a little but I cannot find a way to embed it in a web page. Is there a simple way to do that?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: No, there is not. It is no more 'easier' to do this then run a WinForms program embedded in a browser window. Instead you must target a UI/framework/runtime that *has* browser plugin support - eg. JWS/Applets, Silverlight, Unity 3D, Flash.. There are Python versions for both Java and C# (and as such can potentially be used in the JWS/Silverlight containers), but this wouldn't be with Gtk.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use GTK's [Broadway HTML5 backend](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html) to display your application in a web page.

Comment: Are we sure Broadway is suitable for a public-facing web page now? You would definitely need to make sure your program can't access the rest of the system if you do (and I did ask about this once on IRC but have forgotten any other issues that were brought up).

Comment: I would guess it's not very secure, but the OP didn't say what they wanted it for.

Comment: It supports basic password authentication, but only one user can view the page at a time.